# How to remove everything from a string using numbers to stop at a certain point

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite

So i am trying to make a function that retrieves a time values in the following formate (example)

2y2m2d 2h2M2s

I want python to remove the letters then split it into a list, or i tell the program to look for char y and remove everything apart from the number in front of it.

How could i achieve this?

(using sqlite3)

Comment: Adding some concrete examples of what you want to do would make your question much clearer. Also, it looks like string manipulation, so how does Sqlite come into this?

Comment: do you mean `2020y05m21d 00h00M00s`? try this: `datetime.strptime('2020y05m21d 00h00M00s', '%Yy%mm%dd %Hh%MM%Ss')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using string splitting we can do this

```py
s="1y2m3d 4h5M6s"
#take the numerical values to the string s_nums. Will look like '1,2,3,4,5,6'
s_nums=','.join([n for n in s if n.isdigit()])
#put each of these int values in an array
values = [int(i) for i in s_nums.split(',')]   
print(values)
>>>[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Comment: Ummmm, I think you can just do it in one step: `[int(n) for n in s if n.isdigit()]`